# How to use Mathematica with hardly any financial resources

Tags: education, webmathematica, mathematica-online

I'm a student from Afghanistan and I like to use Mathematica to experiment with as a hobby. But I cannot afford it. Does any one know of a free option?

Comment: One idea would be to use Wolfram Alpha (which is free) and has many of the same capabilities as Mathematica.

Comment: Depending upon your use needs, wolfram cloud basic is free. There are also ways to have a jupyter environment running the wolfram engine that is free for developers. [Here](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) is a link.

Comment: Here's an idea: Have your teacher contact Wolfram (https://www.wolfram.com/contact-us/ ), and ask if they would be willing to donate one copy of Mathematica to your school, which would be installed on a school computer.  Then all the students would have access to it.   He should include a link to the school's website.

Comment: [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) is free, you can use it from command line or [jupyter](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter)

Comment: Since the comments have turned (mostly) into a discussion of constructive alternatives, let me note that a cheap way to get a licensed copy of *Mathematica* is to purchase a Raspberry Pi computer. It's good for other educational purposes, too.

Comment: Ashkan, the topic was cleaned up to conform stack exchange rules. Off topic and obsolete comments were deleted as well. Let's keep it this way.

Answer (score 9):

You can download 15-day trial Mathematica for free with "just an e-mail address" here:

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/

Other solutions presented in comments:

> One idea would be to use **Wolfram Alpha** (which is free) and has many of the same capabilities as Mathematica. – bill s

> Depending upon your use needs, **wolfram cloud** basic is free. There are also ways to have a jupyter environment running the wolfram engine that is free for developers. [Here](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) is a link. – CA Trevillian

> Here's an idea: Have your teacher **contact Wolfram** (wolfram.com/contact-us ), and ask if they would be willing to donate one copy of Mathematica to your school, which would be installed on a school computer. Then all the students would have access to it. He should include a link to the school's website. – theorist

> [**Wolfram Engine**](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) is free, you can use it from command line or [jupyter](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter) – I.M.

> A cheap way to get a licensed copy of Mathematica is to purchase a **Raspberry Pi** computer. It's good for other educational purposes, too. – John Doty

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for your considerate editing of the answer.